# How to enable the Intelligent Text Completion plugin in Gedit

Tags: gedit

I would like Gedit to auto-indent (after function definitions, for example), so I tried installing the plugin [Gedit Intelligent Text Completion](https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-intelligent-text-completion).

Following the instructions, I put `intelligent_text_completion.plugin` inside `.local/share/gedit/plugins` in my home directory, and restarted Gedit. However, if I go to Edit > Preferences > Plugins, the "Intelligent Text Completion" plugin is grayed out:

[image]

Are there any additional steps I missed?

**Update**

If I hover over the field, I see the error message "The plugin 'Intelligent Text Completion' could not be loaded - An error occurred: Failed to load". There is also mention of this in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1207062). Perhaps the plugin just no longer works?

Comment: While I don't know what is causing the issue, I can say that it is not that the plugin no longer works. I successfully installed it on one of my machines yesterday and another machine today.